# ng-if inside ng-repeat not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a repeater that I'm using to return views into an accordion. I'd like to conditionally load the views, so I'm wanting to add an ng-if condition on the repeaters elements to check and see if current == true but it's not working. I'm using Angular 1.0.8.

I have a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GUwSh/14/)

```
<div data-ng-view></div> is showing all the same view
```

Edit:

Angular 1.0.8 does not support ng-if so I went with the switch statement.

```
       <div ng-switch="group.current">
            <div ng-switch-when="true">
                <div data-ng-view></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You should use `ng-include` instead

Comment: Are you able to modify the fiddle and show me ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was at

```
<div ng-if="group.current == 'true'"><div data-ng-view></div></div>
```

replaced with

```
<div ng-if="group.current === true"><div data-ng-view></div></div>
```

check updated at http://jsfiddle.net/rajumjib/GUwSh/15/

Comment: or simply `ng-if="group.current"`

Comment: I tried all of those combinations and they still don't work. I'm using angular 1.0.8. Would that be the issue?